# Non-Hermitian Hamiltonian in the Heisenberg Picture

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hamiltonian, complex-numbers, time-evolution

I am trying to study a system whose Hamiltonian, after some transformations can be written as
\begin{equation}
 \hat{H} = \hat{N}_1(\omega-i\mu)+\hat{N}_2(\omega +i\mu)+\omega\hat{\mathbb{I}},
\end{equation}

where $[\hat{N}_1,\hat{N}_2] = 0$ and the number operators are defined by $\hat{b}_i^{\dagger}\hat{b}_1$, with the ladder operators having the usual commutation relations. I aim to find the evolution of $\hat{b}_1$ in the Heisenberg picture, but I am hesitant about the validity of the Heisenberg equation. I want to ask whether or not my attempt is valid, as I can't seem to find anything similar in any literature. Given that $\hat{H}$ is not Hermitian, the solution for e.g. $\hat{b}_1$ looks like,

\begin{equation}
 \begin{gathered}
  \ [\hat{H},\hat{b}_1]\ =-\hat{b}_1(\omega-i\mu),\hat{H}\hat{b}_1=\hat{b}_1(\hat{H}-\omega+i\mu)\\
 \ [\hat{H}^{\dagger},\hat{b}_1]\ =-\hat{b}_1(\omega+i\mu),\hat{H}^{\dagger}\hat{b}_1=\hat{b}_1(\hat{H}^{\dagger}-\omega-i\mu)
 \end{gathered}\\
 \hat{H}^{\dagger}-\hat{H} = -2i\mu(\hat{N}_2-\hat{N}_1)\\
 \hat{b}_1(t) = \hat{U}^{\dagger}(t)\hat{b}_1\hat{U}(t)=e^{i\hat{H}^{\dagger}t}\hat{b}_1e^{-i\hat{H}t}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(it)^n\hat{H}^{\dagger n}\hat{b}_1}{n!}e^{-i\hat{H}t}=\\
=\hat{b}_1\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(it(\hat{H}^{\dagger}-\omega-i\mu))\frac{1}{n!}e^{-i\hat{H}t}=\hat{b}_1e^{-i\omega t+\mu t+it(\hat{H}^{\dagger}-\hat{H})}=\hat{b}_1e^{-i\omega t+\mu t}e^{2\mu t(\hat{N}_2-\hat{N}_1)}.
\end{equation}
I do not believe have encountered an operator of that form before and I am entirely uncertain if this result is at all correct. I would appreciate any hints or directions towards bibliography which might be of assistance.

Comment: Why are you trying to make a non-Hermitian Hamiltonian? Typically observables are defined to be linear Hermitian operators.

Comment: @MattHanson My task is to make some calculations and test the limits of a certain model when applied to such a system. As per the reasoning behind this specific choice, I have not as of yet been informed. However, I think that in its original form, the Hamiltonian includes an imaginary chemical potential term.